# Share a file in volatile memory between processes without IPC

Tags: android, c, linux, memory, embedded-linux

I have a large file that needs to be accessed (read-only) by several processes. I would like to load the file content into volatile memory at boot and then have the processes access it without communicating with each other.

I was thinking of setting aside physical memory for this purpose, and then hardcode the same physical address in each process. I would let each process make its own mapping to virtual memory, and have one of them write load the file content at boot. Is this possible on Linux (Android)? Is there a better way?

Some more perspective. The file is ~0.5 GB and it's important that read is as fast as possible. Yet the memory is restricted (embedded) so I don't want to have multiple copies of the same file in physical memory. Ideally, I would set aside a contiguous portion of physical memory.

From what I know about mmap, it doesn't load the file directly into memory, instead, it does so in a lazy manner, neither does it allow one to specify which physical memory to allocate to?

I'm thinking about using ION since I am on Android, but it seems to require IPC for sharing a memory handle.

Comment: What about `mmap`?

Comment: Use `mmap` and `mlock`?

Comment: Could you give broader perspective - what should be really done? Accessing physical memory from user process is not possible (maybe user-space drivers would allow this - https://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/fake.html) but I don't think it's good solution.

Comment: @Nabuchodonozor I gave some more perspective. I don't want to access physical memory necessarily, I just want to make sure the virtual memory I access translates to the same physical memory.

Comment: One idea struck me. Maybe I can have a small kernel driver that creates and exports a shared ION handle to userspace.

Comment: Oh, I read about mlock now. That does load everything into RAM and keep it there until you unlock it. So one solution would be for all the processes mmap the file and have one of them also call mlock. A potential downside is that the reservation is not guaranteed, it depends on other processes use of the RAM. In that sense, it would be more explicit and safe to reserve an ION heap via the device tree, but then again I would need to share the ion handle somehow.

Comment: *"I would set aside a contiguous portion of physical memory"* -- Why use a method so complicated?  If there's enough RAM to hold the entire file, then simply use **tmpfs**.

Comment: @sawdust so basically move the file to /tmp (assuming it's a mount point of tmpfs) and I'm good to go?

Comment: @user2251965 -- *Copy* (not move) the file to **/tmp** and you're good to go (i.e. read from fs cache).

Comment: A problem with tmpfs (or mmap+mlock) is that the memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous. So it doesn't work if hardware blocks with such a requirement are going to operate on it, which is often the case in embedded systems. And it seems that reserving contiguous memory is not possible from userspace, it must be handled by the kernel (some discussion https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/840213/).

Comment: *"the memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous"* -- You mean *physical* memory?  *"it doesn't work if hardware ..."* -- If the SoC has a MMU, then it probably has a DMAC with buffer-chaining capability.  (At least Atmel /Microchip SAM9 & SAMA5 chips do.) So a transfer can use non-contiguous *physical* memory.

Comment: @sawdust I was referring to physical memory. And yes, buffer-chaining is a good point.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't just use classic RAM disk approach? With Linux you can add something like `mkdir /tmp/memdisk; mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m myramdisk /tmp/memdisk; cp your_file /tmp/memdisk` to one of your system init scripts and just access the file from here. The only real downside of it is that you need root access but for custom embedded devices this should not be a problem.

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of that. Besides root access, are there any other caveats/risks I should be aware of? Any overhead involved with tmpfs?

Comment: Tmpfs is not *"classic RAM disk"*.  See **Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt**.  The **/tmp** directory is probably already the mount point of a tmpfs, so your answer creates another tmpfs within a tmpfs.

Comment: /tmp is just an example, you can mount it wherever you want. The only caveat is the fact that the fixed amount of memory you requested + some overhead gets consumed by the disk cache and if you don't have enough memory left for applications then you are out of luck. But that is always the case no matter what kind of a RAM disk you may use. The performance difference between ramfs, tmpfs and other options should also be negligible. But tmpfs is pretty much guaranteed to be supported by the Linux kernel of your platform and it has all the bells and whistles of a real file system.